# Blogger soho: erase tag bar

Tags: html, blogger

Inside a post or static page, there is a bar between the side bar and the content of the page/post. I find that bar excessively wide and I would like to srhink it, erase it, or move it to the bottom of the post/page. How? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? Please read the guidelines on creating an example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Look in your CSS you both have a "nav-bar" class or something but with your CSS code it would be easier to help you

Comment: I do not have a "nav-bar" class, sorry.

Comment: I do not know which CSS should I copy. The whole template is longer than allowed :/

Comment: Can you put it on github so we will be able to check it. You can search the name of the "class" by using : right click on your page then inspect then choose the inspection cursor and you will be able to find the name of the class of this object.  You can find a good tuto there : https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/

Comment: Thank you for your time and consideration. Finally I have decided to change the template. I found the class of the bar: it is called post-side bar, and its width can be varied with px. Unfortunately, I was not able to move the bar to the bottom of the posts.

Comment: So this subject is closed ? Or you still need help ?